# Trying to understand quotient group subraction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces

Say I have $R/I$ where, $$[a]=a+I$$

Then if $[a]=[b]$ does that mean $(a-b) + I=[0] $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $[a]=[b]\iff a+I=b+I \iff a=b+i$ for some $i\in I$. Therefore, $a-b=i$ and $(a-b)+I=i+I=I=0+I=[0]$.

Comment: Say we were dealing with quotient rings with [0] defined, am I correct in thinking this wouldn't imply $a-b=0$ ?

Comment: You are correct. As I said, it implies that $a-b=i\in I$. It could be that $i=0$, but in general that's not true (except if $I=\{0\}$).